# Error binary '==' no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Item' ( or there is no acceptable conversion ) C2678 and C2064

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a beginner trying to code a text adventure game, and I'm getting errors C2678 and C2064 in the `Player` class. I'm unsure on how to fix it, as the error mentions the `Item` class, the function `bool Location::takeItem()`, `Player::dropItem()` and `Player::TakeItem()` are giving me errors when using `std::find()` and the iterator.

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Location.h"

bool Player::hasItem(Item* i)
{
    if (std::find(pInventory.begin(), pInventory.end(), i) != pInventory.end())
        cout << i->GetName() << " is in Inventory" << endl;
    else
        cout << i->GetName() << " is not in inventory" << endl;

}

bool Player::takeItem(Item* i)
{
    Item tempItem = *i; // dereference the pointer

    // find if item is in the contents of 
    if (std::find(pLocation.contents.begin(), pLocation.contents.end(), i) != pLocation.contents.end()) {
        pInventory.push_back(tempItem); // put the item in player inventory
        vector<Item>::iterator position = std::find(pLocation.contents.begin(), pLocation.contents.end(), i);
        pLocation.contents.erase(position);

        cout << "Take Item Success" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Take Item Failure" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
        

bool Player::dropItem(Item* i)
{

    Item tempItem = *i; // dereference the pointer

    // find if item is in the contents of the player inventory
    if (std::find(pInventory.begin(), pInventory.end(), i) != pInventory.end()) { //this is the code throwing the error
        pLocation.contents.push_back(tempItem); // drop item at current players location
        vector<Item>::iterator position = (std::find(pInventory.begin(), pInventory.end(), i));
        pInventory.erase(position); // erase the item from the player inventory
        cout << "Drop " << tempItem.GetName() << " Success" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << " Drop " << tempItem.GetName() << " Failed / Does not exist " << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

bool Player::openItem(Item* i)
{
    return false;
}

void Player::printStatus()
{
    cout << "Your location is:    ";
        cout <<pLocation.name << endl;
    cout << " The contents in your inventory are:    " << endl;
    for (auto items : pInventory)
        cout << items.GetName() << "  ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << " The number of current steps taken:    " << pSteps << endl;
}

Player::Player(Location loc)
{
    
    pLocation = loc;
}
```

Location.cpp

```
#include "Location.h"
#include "Player.h"

Location::Location() { DefaultValues(); }
//Location::Location(string name, string description) { DefaultValues(name, description); }

Location::Location(string name, string description, vector<Item> contents) {
    this->name = name;
    this->description = description;
    this->contents = contents;
}

//which displays the location’s description and the current list of items
void Location::print()
{
    cout << "You are currently located at: " << name << endl;
    cout << description << endl;
    cout << "Current List of Items Include: " << endl;
    for (Item i : contents)
    {
        cout << i.GetName()<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// to remove an item from the location; returns true/false for success / failure(because the item may not be here)
bool Location::takeItem(Item* i) 
{

    Item tempItem = *i;//dereference the pointer
    //this is the code throwing the error
    
    
    if (std::find(contents.begin(), contents.end(), i) != contents.end()) {
        vector<Item>::iterator position = std::find_if(contents.begin(), contents.end(), i);
        contents.erase(position);
        cout << tempItem.GetName() << " Was added to the inventory" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << tempItem.GetName() << " Action Failed / Does not exist" << endl;
        return false;
    }
        
    
}

// to add an item to the location
void Location::dropItem(Item* i) // try an iteration for loop for the function as there could be multiple o9f the same item in a vector
{
    Item tempItem = *i; //dereference the pointer.
    contents.push_back(tempItem);
    cout << tempItem.GetName() << " Has been dropped " << endl;

    /*if (std::find(player.pInventory.begin(), player.pInventory.end(), i) != player.pInventory.end()) {
        contents.push_back(tempItem);
        std::vector<Item>::iterator position = std::find(player.pInventory.begin(), player.pInventory.end(), i);
        player.pInventory.erase(position);

        cout << tempItem.GetName() << " Has been dropped " << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << tempItem.GetName() << " Action Failed / Does not exist " << endl;*/

    /*bool hasdropped = false;

    for (auto& droppedItem : player->pInventory) {
        if (i->GetName() == droppedItem.GetName()) {
            contents.push_back(droppedItem);
            vector<Item>    ::iterator it = std::find(player->pInventory.begin(), player->pInventory.end(), i->GetName());
            if (it != player->pInventory.end())
                contents.erase(it);
            hasdropped = true;
        }

        if (hasdropped == true)
            break;
    }*/
    
}

// to get the key item required to go in some direction; returns nullptr if no item required
Item* Location::getKey(string& direction)
{
    return nullptr;
}

// to get the location the direction leads to; returns null if you cannot got in that direction from this location
 Location* Location::getConnection(string& direction)
{
    return nullptr;
}


void Location::SetLocations(Location* ptrNorth, Location* ptrSouth, Location* ptrEast, Location* ptrWest)
{
    ptrLocationNorth = ptrNorth;
    ptrLocationSouth = ptrSouth;
    ptrLocationEast = ptrEast;
    ptrLocationWest = ptrWest;
}

void Location::DefaultValues(string name, string description)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->description = description;

    /*ptrLocationNorth = nullptr;
    ptrLocationSouth = nullptr;
    ptrLocationEast = nullptr;
    ptrLocationWest = nullptr;*/
}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Globals.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "Location.h"



static class Player
{
public:
    //p stands for player
    static vector<Item> pInventory;
    static Location pLocation;
    static int pSteps;
    
public:
    bool hasItem(Item* i);// to check if an item is in the inventory.
    bool takeItem(Item* i);// to add an item to the inventory; returns true/false to indicate success / failure(because the item may not be here).
    bool dropItem(Item* i);// to drop an item at the current location; returns true / false to indicate success / failure(because you may not have the item).
    bool openItem(Item* i); //to open an item; returns true/false to indicate success / failure(e.g.because the item is not a container, its open method fails.

    static void printStatus(); //to display the current location, inventory, and number of steps.
    
    Player();
    Player(Location loc);

};
```

Location.h

```
#pragma once
#include"Globals.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include <algorithm>


class Location
{
//member variables
#pragma region Variables
public:
    int number;
    string name;
    string description;
    vector<Item> contents;
    vector<Location> keyItems;
    //Player player;
    
//pointer variables to the specified directions
    Location* ptrLocationNorth;
    Location* ptrLocationSouth;
    Location* ptrLocationEast;
    Location* ptrLocationWest;

//connections (maps each possible direction to the location it leads to)
#pragma endregion
#pragma region Functions
//class member functions
public:
    void print();
    bool takeItem(Item* i);
    void dropItem(Item* i);
    Item* getKey(string& direction);
    Location* getConnection(string& direction);

    void SetLocations(Location* ptrNorth, Location* ptrSouth, Location* ptrEast, Location* ptrWest);
    void DefaultValues(string name = "", string description = "");

    Location();//default constructor
    //Location(string name, string description); // initialise the variables through the constructor
    Location(string name, string description, vector<Item> contents); // initialise the variables through the constructor
    

#pragma endregion
};
```

Item.h

```
#pragma once
#include"Globals.h"

class Item
{
private:
    string name;
    string description;
public:
    //getter
    string GetName() const;
    string GetDescription() const;
    ////setter
    virtual bool operator==(const Item& rhs) const {
        return name == rhs.name;
    }
public:
    Item();
    Item(string name, string description);
};
```

Item.cpp

```
#include "Item.h"

string Item::GetName() const
{
    return name;
}

string Item::GetDescription() const
{
    return description;
}

Item::Item()
{
}

Item::Item(string name, string description)
{
}
```

I tried to add an operator to the `Item` class, and it fixed one of the errors, but there are still errors within the `Player` and `Location` classes using `std::find()`.

Comment: You are trying to compare `Item` to `Item*`, these are not the same.

Comment: `Player::pInventory` and `Location::contents` hold elements of type `Item`, but `Player::hasItem()` and `Location::takeItem()` are searching for `Item*` pointers instead of `Item` objects. I agree with Yksisarvinen, there are too many pointers in this code where pointers are not needed.

Comment: The question doesn't meet the requirements of [mcve] that makes it unlikely searchable and useful to other users.